# How to print and preserve left-to-right order with unicode

Tags: python-2.7, unicode-string

I am trying to print, in a single line, a string followed by a space and then followed by a number. The string comes from a long list in unicode and some of them (but not all) are in the right-to-left format. My problem is that the order I want is reversed when I use strings in this format.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
line1='abcd'
line2='אבגד'
print line1+' '+str(1)
print line2+' '+str(1)
```

The ouput is

```
abcd 1
אבגד1
```

The first output is in the desired order, but the second one is not. Is there a way to avoid this reversal?

Also, I am required to only use the the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a left-to-right mark (represented as u'\u200E') at the beginning of the string you are printing. This is an invisible character that will enforce the direction of text, so it will not negatively affect text that is already meant to be printed this way. The following code produces the desired output:

```
print u'\u200E'+line1+' '+str(1)
print u'\u200E'+line2+' '+str(1)
```

For more information see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark

Comment: At first I thought I would need to figure out first which strings were in right-to-left languages, but it turns out I can just add that character to all of the strings with no negative side effects. Also, through testing I figured out it needs to be _before_, not after the strings. I could post a more complete answer based on this, but I am unsure whether it would be good etiquette.